Helm index.yaml not updated after deploying new Helm chart to JFrog Artifactory
I recently started seeing some odd behavior wherein after deploying a new Helm chart to JFrog Artifactory 7.46.6, that repo's index.yaml is not updated -- I must manually re-calculate the index for it to appear in index.yaml. This is not something I've ever had to do before.
The deployment tool I use to resolve packages relies on index.yaml, so this is causing all sorts of deployment problems right now. Prior to this, I could upload a Helm chart to Artifactory, and then immediately deploy it without having to do any kind of manual intervention.
Below is an example PowerShell script I am using to test this behavior. For this exercise, I am deploying directly to a local repo.
$creds = Get-Credential

Invoke-WebRequest "https://artifactory.foo.bar/artifactory/helm-local/foo/bar/mychart-9.9.1.tgz" -Credential $creds -Method PUT -InFile "mychart-9.9.1.tgz"

The chart is successfully deployed as expected, but if I view values.yaml, I cannot find this chart until I manually re-index the repo.
Some other things I've tried:

Manually deploying via the Artifactory GUI

Deploying directly to one of our two Artifactory nodes (we have HA on our apps)


The repo in question is also part of a virtual repo -- I looked in that repo's values.yaml and couldn't find the package there either.
At this point I'm really just trying to find out what the expected behavior is -- does Artifactory handle auto-updating index.yaml or is it expected that a user manually does this? I've done so much Googling and I cannot find a simple yes/no answer to this question. I've also been poking around the Artifactory settings and I cannot find anything related to auto-indexing (such as enabling/disabling it, setting the interval, etc.), unless these are buried deep in some config files that I can't see from the front-end.
If Artifactory auto-reindexes then something changed in our configuration and we can try and put it back. If Artifactory does not auto-reindex then I have no clue how this was ever working for us.
